# Group the results in a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure that returns a table. One column in that table is the result of a T-SQL function. That function returns a 0 or 1 based on an ID. The stored procedure accepts IDs stored in XML.

The function is quite complex so I will omit it here, but basically the function `ForeignVendor` takes an ID and returns 0 or 1.

The function takes an xml argument and returns a table. I need this function as is. I am hoping to reuse it.

Here is the function:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE ForeignVendors
    @VendorIDs xml
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT 
        VEN_POName, 
        T.Item.value('@VendorID[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS "VendorID", 
        ForeignVendor(T.Item.value('@VendorID[1]', 'varchar(10)')) AS "ForeignFlag"
    FROM 
        VEN V
    JOIN 
        @VendorIDs.nodes('/Root/Vendor') AS T(Item) ON V.VEN_VendorID = T.Item.value('@VendorID[1]', 'varchar(10)')
END
```

I can call it like this

```
exec [Rotair_ForeignVendors] N'<Root><Vendor VendorID="000010"/><Vendor VendorID="000011"/><Vendor VendorID="000198"/><Vendor VendorID="000021"/></Root>'
```

and get this back

```
NEMITZ TOOL CO.         000021  0
P & W CANADA HELICOPTER 000198  1
SHOP                    000011  0
ILS                     000010  0
```

One report need to know if any 1's exist in the last column. I was trying to pass the results to a group by query but that does not work.

Any suggestions on the most efficient way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this?

```
CREATE TABLE #results
(
    Vendor VARCHAR(1000),
    VendorID varchar(20),
    ForeignFlag BIT
);

INSERT INTO #results
EXEC [Rotair_ForeignVendors] N'<Root><Vendor VendorID="000010"/><Vendor VendorID="000011"/><Vendor VendorID="000198"/><Vendor VendorID="000021"/></Root>';

SELECT COUNT(ForeignFlag)
FROM #results
WHERE ForeignFlag = 1;

DROP TABLE #results;
```

Comment: Works perfect.  I was hoping not to have to process the overhead of creating a table.  But I presume that it creates it in memory and may not be so bad.  If no one comes up with something less complex I will mark yours as the answer.

Comment: It's not that bad to create a table in tempdb at all unless you are doing it within a cycle with lots of iterations. One more suggestion - you don't need a `group by` and aggregation to check for existence of something - use `exists()` instead.

Comment: @Ivan - I think you misunderstand.  If not then please tell me how I would use exists to determine if a column in the table posted above has a value of a 1 in any row.  Keep in mind that the 1 or 0 is the result of a function.

Comment: @joe now i don't understand. The only purpose of `exists` is to find out whether there is any row satisfying conditions or not. I don't understand what are you asking. if exists 1 else 0. What is the question?

Comment: @Ivan - I have no clue where you got exists 1 else 0.  No wonder you're confused, that confuses me.  I would be happy to explain whatever you do not understand.  Please state fully what you do not understand.